# Display Random Images from an array for multiple images with FadeIN/Out in Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript

I can't use for multiple images! Any ideas, please.

Here is my html code:

```
<img src="bomb.gif" id="showRandom" class="random" alt=""> 
<img src="smile.gif" id="showRandom" class="random" alt=""> 
<img src="frown.gif" id="showRandom" class="random" alt="">
```

JS:

```
var img_array = ["bomb.gif", "frown.gif", "grim.gif", "smile.gif"];

setInterval(function randomImages () {
  var randomImage = img_array[Math.floor(Math.random()*img_array.length)];

 document.querySelector("#showRandom").src = randomImage;
}, 1500);
```

---

Comment: What is your exact question ? where you're facing problem ?

Comment: Here is my html code. I can't use for mulitple images! Any ideas, please. <img src="bomb.gif" id="showRandom" class="random" alt="">

  <img src="smile.gif" id="showRandom" class="random" alt="">

  <img src="frown.gif" id="showRandom" class="random" alt="">

Comment: is the issue that the images are not changing or that you want to know how to implement the fadeIn/fadeOut?

Comment: only first image is changing, and also I want to know how to implement fadeIn/fadeout? Thanks

Comment: @saw ID's must be unique, you can't have more than one element with the same ID (`id="showRandom"`), you need to select by class, for example `document.querySelector('.random:nth-of-type(1)')` (First element), `document.querySelector('.random:nth-of-type(2)')` (Second element) and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var img_array = ["bomb.gif", "frown.gif", "grim.gif", "smile.gif"];

  setInterval(function randomImages () {
    var randomImage = img_array[Math.floor(Math.random()*img_array.length)];
    var imgNode = document.querySelector("#showRandom"); 
    
   imgNode.classList.remove('random');
   imgNode.classList.add('transitioning-src');
   
   setTimeout(() => {
    imgNode.src = randomImage;
                imgNode.classList.remove('transitioning-src');
    imgNode.classList.add('random');
            }, 400);
   document.querySelector(".imgsrc").value = randomImage;
  }, 3000);
```

```css
.transitioning-src {
    transition: opacity .4s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .4s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity .4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .4s ease-out;
    opacity: 0;
   }
   #showRandom {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
        border: 1px solid black;
   }
   .random{
    transition: opacity .4s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .4s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity .4s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: opacity .4s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity .4s ease-in;
    opacity: 1;
   }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="imgsrc"/><br />
 <img src="avatar.png" id="showRandom" class="random" alt="" />
```